# Accordion only correctly functions correctly after a page reload?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ruby-on-rails

Any idea why this might be? I'm rather stumped. It works fine after a page reload, but when you initially land there it does not minimize the tabs, it only can open them all. I'm using bootstrap framework within rails.

If you want to see what I mean, follow this link (https://portfoliobogart.herokuapp.com/static_pages/design), and then click on the "Sharko's Wireframe" card. You'll see what I mean regarding my error.

```css
.accordion-panel {
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  -webkit-transition: background-color 0.8s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: background-color 0.8s ease-in-out;
  transition: background-color 0.5s ease-in-out;
  border-left: none!important;
  border-right: none!important;
  border-top: none!important;
  box-shadow: none;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
.accordion-title {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 100!important;
  padding: .75em!important;
  border-top-left-radius: 10px;
  border-top-right-radius: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 0!important;
}
.accordion-title>a:hover {
  text-decoration: none!important;
}
.accordion-content {
  margin: 0em 3em 3em 3em;
}
.divider {
  height: 3px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  margin: 0em 3em 3em 3em;
}
@media (min-width: 450px) {
  h1.heading {
    font-size: 3.55em;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 760px) {
  h1.heading {
    font-size: 3.05em;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 900px) {
  h1.heading {
    font-size: 3.25em;
    margin: 0 0 0.3em;
    margin-top: auto;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<section style="padding: 6em 0em;">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <hr>
      <div id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
        <div class="card accordion-panel">
          <div class="card-block accordion-heading" role="tab" id="headingOne">
            <h3 class="card-title accordion-title">
                            <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
                          Wireframe #1
                        </a>
                      </h3>
          </div>
          <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne">
            <div class="accordion-content">
              <div class="divider"></div>
              <div id="wireframePics">
                <%=i mage_tag( "sharkoWire1.JPG", class: "img-responsive")%>
              </div>
              <p class="lead">
                Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird
                on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table,
                raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card accordion-panel">
          <div class="card-block accordion-heading" role="tab" id="headingTwo">
            <h3 class="card-title accordion-title">
                        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
                          Wireframe #2
                        </a>
                      </h3>
          </div>
          <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingTwo">
            <div class="accordion-content">
              <div class="divider"></div>
              <div id="wireframePics">
                <%=i mage_tag( "sharkoWire1.JPG", class: "img-responsive")%>
              </div>
              <p class="lead">
                Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird
                on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table,
                raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card accordion-panel">
          <div class="card-block accordion-heading" role="tab" id="headingThree">
            <h3 class="card-title accordion-title">
                        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseThree" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseThree">
                          Wireframe #3
                        </a>
                      </h3>
          </div>
          <div id="collapseThree" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingThree">
            <div class="accordion-content">
              <div class="divider"></div>
              <div id="wireframePics">
                <%=i mage_tag( "sharkoWire1.JPG", class: "img-responsive")%>
              </div>
              <p class="lead">
                Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird
                on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table,
                raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card accordion-panel">
          <div class="card-block accordion-heading" role="tab" id="headingFour">
            <h3 class="card-title accordion-title">
                        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseFour" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseFour">
                          Wireframe #4
                        </a>
                      </h3>
          </div>
          <div id="collapseFour" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingFour">
            <div class="accordion-content">
              <div class="divider"></div>
              <div id="wireframePics">
                <%=i mage_tag( "sharkoWire1.JPG", class: "img-responsive")%>
              </div>
              <p class="lead">
                Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird
                on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table,
                raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card accordion-panel">
          <div class="card-block accordion-heading" role="tab" id="headingFive">
            <h3 class="card-title accordion-title">
                        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseFive" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseFive">
                          Wireframe #5
                        </a>
                      </h3>
          </div>
          <div id="collapseFive" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingFive">
            <div class="accordion-content">
              <div class="divider"></div>
              <div id="wireframePics">
                <%=i mage_tag( "sharkoWire1.JPG", class: "img-responsive")%>
              </div>
              <p class="lead">
                Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird
                on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table,
                raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: I regret screwing up that title -_-

Comment: I have updated your codes they seem to be working fine mate

Comment: Did you follow that link I have? It only works once the page is reloaded for me.. :/

Comment: I have seen the site I was able to minimize the panels what seem to be wrong here can you explain more in detail?

Comment: The tabs are not minimizing for me, they only can open up when initially navigating there. Only once I refresh the page can I minimize the tabs and reopen them. I'd like for the tabs to be able to open AND minimize upon initial landing. See what I'm saying?

Comment: yes mate have you seen the update on your posting try that you would see that you could already minimize the tabs.

Comment: and on your site @MrJesus its working just fine for me try removing cache